# How to select and join field with max date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have two tables joined on RECID and AAATRANSPORTORDERRECID :

AAATRANSPORTTABLE

```
Pro Number  Bill Date   CREATEDDATETIME         RECID
14521857    2019-04-10  2019-06-04 21:53:09.000 5637146183
```

AAALTLCHANGEREQUEST

```
AAAREFNUMVALUE  AAALTLCHANGEVALUE   RECID        CREATEDDATETIME              AAATRANSPORTORDERRECID
14521857        Edit Cycle          5637655326   2020-01-21 14:26:31.000        5637146183
14521857        Ready to Invoice    5637656076   2020-01-21 14:29:24.000        5637146183
14521857        Invoiced            5637656098   2020-01-21 16:04:39.000        5637146183
```

I need to select the record shown from AAATRANSPORTTABLE and join the AAALTLCHANGEVALUE value for the most recent CREATEDDATETIME from AAALTLCHANGEREQUEST. My query is as below:

```
SELECT

    t.[Pro Number],
    t.CREATEDDATETIME,
    t.[Bill Date],
    t.RECID,
    l.AAALTLCHANGEVALUE,
    max(l.CREATEDDATETIME) as Status_Date


FROM [AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[AAATRANSPORTTABLE_V] t
LEFT JOIN AX2cTestAdapter_dbo_AAALTLCHANGEREQUEST_V l 
ON t.RECID = l.AAATRANSPORTORDERRECID

WHERE t.[Pro Number] = '14521857'

GROUP by l.CREATEDDATETIME,t.[Pro Number],t.CREATEDDATETIME,t.[Bill Date],t.RECID,l.AAALTLCHANGEVALUE
```

It produces these results:

```
Pro Number  Bill Date     CREATEDDATETIME              RECID        AAALTLCHANGEVALUE   Status_Date
14521857    2019-04-10    2019-06-04 21:53:09.000     5637146183    Edit Cycle          2020-03-24 11:42:52.000
14521857    2019-04-10    2019-06-04 21:53:09.000     5637146183    Ready to Invoice    2020-03-24 11:51:00.000
14521857    2019-04-10    2019-06-04 21:53:09.000     5637146183    Invoiced            2020-03-24 11:52:08.000
```

My desired output is

```
Pro Number  Bill Date   CREATEDDATETIME         RECID       AAALTLCHANGEVALUE  Status_Date
14521857    2019-04-10  2019-06-04 21:53:09.000 5637146183  Invoiced           2020-03-24 11:52:08.000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are selecting max(l.CREATEDDATETIME) in your select query but you are not doing anything to select the max date in your where clause. You have to put a where clause to select the row with max date out of your 3 rows. I have tried to modify your query, you might need to modify the table and column name but you will get the context once you go through it -

```
SELECT

    t.[Pro Number],
    t.CREATEDDATETIME,
    t.[Bill Date],
    t.RECID,
    l.AAALTLCHANGEVALUE,
    l.CREATEDDATETIME as Status_Date


FROM [AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[AAATRANSPORTTABLE_V] t
LEFT JOIN AX2cTestAdapter_dbo_AAALTLCHANGEREQUEST_V l 
ON t.RECID = l.AAATRANSPORTORDERRECID

WHERE t.[Pro Number] = '14521857'
AND l.CREATEDDATETIME = (select max(V.CREATEDDATETIME) from AX2cTestAdapter_dbo_AAALTLCHANGEREQUEST_V V where V.AAAREFNUMVALUE = '14521857')

GROUP by l.CREATEDDATETIME,t.[Pro Number],t.CREATEDDATETIME,t.[Bill Date],t.RECID,l.AAALTLCHANGEVALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to get that desired result from your data because that given date in desired data even doesn't exist in any of the tables. However, from your definition this should be what you are after:

```
SELECT

    t.[ProNumber],
    t.CREATEDDATETIME,
    t.[BillDate],
    t.RECID,
    l.AAALTLCHANGEVALUE,
    l.CREATEDDATETIME as Status_Date


FROM [AAATRANSPORTTABLE] t
LEFT JOIN (
    select t1.AAATRANSPORTORDERRECID, t1.AAALTLCHANGEVALUE, t1.CREATEDDATETIME 
    from AAALTLCHANGEREQUEST t1
    inner join (
          select AAATRANSPORTORDERRECID, max(CREATEDDATETIME) as maxDate 
          from AAALTLCHANGEREQUEST
          group by AAATRANSPORTORDERRECID) t2 
          on t1.AAATRANSPORTORDERRECID = t2.AAATRANSPORTORDERRECID 
             and t1.CREATEDDATETIME = t2.MaxDate) l
    ON t.RECID = l.AAATRANSPORTORDERRECID
WHERE t.[ProNumber] = '14521857';
```

[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a67d7c04ecea16c17f05cd8f90b089a9)

PS: You don't need any group by on the main select, it is needed only for getting the max date per group.